# Will Juju support Cluster-API like microk8s dooes?

Tags: juju, kubernetes, microk8s

Recently I found out about Cluster-API in k8s -> https://cluster-api.sigs.k8s.io/reference/providers and the Idea behind it. After a bit of research, I found https://github.com/canonical/cluster-api-bootstrap-provider-microk8s and that microk8s is basically supported. There is also activity in the different Repos, and microk8s is mentioned on the Provider List.

Also found a JuJu based Provider, but no Information if the provider will be supported in the future. Both Developers don't work for Canonical anymore and there is no recent activity in the Repositories.

Is the JuJu Provider born "dead"? Or can we expect more activity in the future?